# Kubernetes cluster - Cannot access Kafka broker running in a pod from spring boot service running in another pod in multi VM k8s cluster

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, kubernetes-pod

I have a Kafka broker running in a multi VM environment (Private cloud - with our own Kubernetes cluster - 4 node cluster).

I have created a spring boot application that has a publisher that has to publish a message to the Kafka topic inside the Kafka broker. I have both the containers(Kafka broker & spring boot app) running in the same Kubernetes cluster.

I couldn't access the Kafka broker (running in the same k8s cluster) by providing the Kafka's service name: port id in the publisher's bootstrap.servers

Spring boot's publisher configuration:

```
 props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "kafka-svc:9092");- -> not working
```

**Cluster information:**

kafka-broker yaml file:

```yaml
    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: kafka-deploy
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: kafka
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: kafka
        spec:
          containers:
          - env:
            - name: KAFKA_PORT
              value: "9092"
            - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT
              value: "9092"
            - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME
              value: kafka-svc
            - name: KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS
              value: "test:1:1"
            - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
              value: zookeeper-svc:2181
            - name: KAFKA_BROKER_ID
              value: "1"
            name: kafka
            image: wurstmeister/kafka
            ports:
            - containerPort: 9092
    ------
       apiVersion: v1
       kind: Service
       metadata:
         name: kafka-svc
       spec:
         type: NodePort
         ports:
         - port: 9092
           targetPort: 9092
           name: http
           protocol: TCP
         selector:
           app: kafka
           kafka-broker-id: "1"
```

When I attempt to push a string message on to Kafka topic, I am getting the below exception:

```sh
"2020-08-18 13:28:04.525  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1597757284523
2020-08-18 13:29:04.539 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.k.support.LoggingProducerListener    : Exception thrown when sending a message with key='null' and payload='TEST' to topic test:

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic test not present in metadata after 60000 ms.

2020-08-18 13:29:04.544 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Send failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic test not present in metadata after 60000 ms.] with root cause
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to create *`test`* topic before you can publish anything.

You can see if the topic is available in your Kafka cluster. For example from the one of Kafka broker pods:

```sh
bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --zookeeper zookeeper-svc:2181 --topic test --describe
```

Or you can create it on your Spring Boot app:

```java
package io.stockgeeks.kafka.config;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.NewTopic;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.TopicBuilder;

@Configuration
public class KafkaTopicConfiguration {
  
  @Bean
  public NewTopic topicExample() {
    return TopicBuilder.name("test")
      .partitions(6)
      .replicas(3)
      .build();
  }
}
```

✌️